# Connect two machines in AKKA remotely ,connection refused

Tags: scala, akka

I'm new to akka and wanted to connect two PC using akka remotely just to run some code in both as (2 actors). I had tried the example in [akka doc](https://developer.lightbend.com/start/?group=akka&project=akka-samples-cluster-scala). But what I really do is to add the 2 IP addresses into config file I always get this error?

First machine give me this error:

> [info] [ERROR] [11/20/2018 13:58:48.833]
>   [ClusterSystem-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-6]
>   [akka.remote.artery.Association(akka://ClusterSystem)] Outbound
>   control stream to [akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.1.2:2552] failed.
>   Restarting it. Handshake with [akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.1.2:2552]
>   did not complete within 20000 ms
>   (akka.remote.artery.OutboundHandshake$HandshakeTimeoutException:
>   Handshake with [akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.1.2:2552] did not
>   complete within 20000 ms)

And second machine:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   akka.remote.RemoteTransportException: Failed to bind TCP to
>   [192.168.1.3:2552] due to: Bind failed because of
>   java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind

Config file content :

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = cluster
  }
  remote {
    artery {
      enabled = on
      transport = tcp
      canonical.hostname = "192.168.1.3"
      canonical.port = 0
    }
  }
  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.1.3:2552",
      "akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.1.2:2552"]

    # auto downing is NOT safe for production deployments.
    # you may want to use it during development, read more about it in the docs.
    auto-down-unreachable-after = 120s
  }
}

# Enable metrics extension in akka-cluster-metrics.
akka.extensions=["akka.cluster.metrics.ClusterMetricsExtension"]

# Sigar native library extract location during tests.
# Note: use per-jvm-instance folder when running multiple jvm on one host.
akka.cluster.metrics.native-library-extract-folder=${user.dir}/target/native
```

Comment: First of all you need to fix binding problem on the second pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to add cluster configuration for AKKA remoting. Both the PCs or nodes should be enabled remoting with a concrete port instead of "0" that way you know which port to connect.

Have below configurations

PC1

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = remote
  }
  remote {
    artery {
      enabled = on
      transport = tcp
      canonical.hostname = "192.168.1.3"
      canonical.port = 19000
    }
  }
}
```

PC2

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = remote
  }
  remote {
    artery {
      enabled = on
      transport = tcp
      canonical.hostname = "192.168.1.4"
      canonical.port = 18000
    }
  }
}
```

Use below actor path to connect any actor in remote from PC1 to PC2

```
akka://<PC2-ActorSystem>@192.168.1.4:18000/user/<actor deployed in PC2>
```

Use below actor path to connect from PC2 to PC1

```
akka://<PC2-ActorSystem>@192.168.1.3:19000/user/<actor deployed in PC1>
```

Port numbers and IP address are samples.

Comment: Thanks.Could I know where to add the actor paths ,is it in the conf file If so what is the syntax ?

Comment: I think you need to understand the basics of AKKA and Actor model. You may google or you may look at this tutorial https://www.javatpoint.com/akka-tutorial